# Link json file into html body

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this Json file which I tried to load into the html body using the script tag as shown below.

The below would be the html file

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="category"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tsTree.js"></script>  

<script type="application/json" src="gwf.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please let me know. thanks in advance...

Comment: script tag is only to add js files. I may think that the json file is on the server side, not client. You can get it via ajax for exemple.

Comment: @hathija no offense but can you back up your statement with a reference to the <script/> tag specification?

Comment: What are you expecting loading a JSON file to do? `<script>` is for executable scripting languages, JSON is just data, nothing to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XMLHttpRequest`for example like this:

```js
function loadJSON(URL, callback) {

  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET',URL, true); 

  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
}
```

Where callback is a function that takes the response ( i.e. the json ) and use it.